# How to keep the Hello-world container running

Tags: docker, containers

I am leaning docker and the first container I started was hello-world, but I noticed that the container is getting stopped right after printing all the welcome notes. So my question is, is there any way I can keep this container running for as long as I want?

Comment: Have you had a look at the Dockerfiles for this image to see what they actually do? https://github.com/docker-library/hello-world

Comment: What is the reason you would like this container to be running? What would you like to achieve?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can not make it running for a long, as the [hello-world](https://github.com/docker-library/hello-world/blob/master/amd64/hello-world/Dockerfile) docker is from scratch and there is no bash or sh or any other bash command, so it will exit once it prints HelloWorld.  it just container `hello` executable file.

```
FROM scratch
COPY hello /
CMD ["/hello"]
```

You can play with alpine, a minimal image.

```
docker run -it --rm --name helloworld alpine ash -c "echo helloworld ; sh"
```

Comment: I ended up using `nginx`, but on an aside if you need the container to keep running don't use the run command. Run is for creating and starting the container. Just create the container and then use the start command. This way you aren't locked into the running container context. Allows you to step away.